# View schema in parquet with on command line parquet-tools

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I'm trying to run a [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) command to only view the file schema of my parquet file.

I am currently running:

```sh
$ parquet-tools meta /tmp/my-file.parquet
```

But this displays the file schema *plus* hundreds of row groups.  I don't want to see the row groups, only the file schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
parquet-tools schema /tmp/my-file.parquet
```

Answer (score 1):

you can open it using python with

`pip install fastparquet`

and then

```
import pandas as pd
song_embeddings = pd.read_parquet('user_features_test_svd.parquet')
print(song_embeddings)
```